# Load Google Maps AFTER everything else has loaded

Tags: jquery, css, google-maps-api-3, window, load

I am using some cloud fonts on my website with the Google Maps JavaScript API.

To avoid showing the font "transforming" into the cloud font I have set, I've put in some basic code to hide the body tag initially and then load it after everything has finished loading:

**JS:**

```
$(window).on('load', function() { 
    $("body").fadeIn('fast');
});
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    display: none;
}
```

The code works fine on its own but the problem is getting the Google Map to load properly with it. As you can see in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lfq1negw/) the map does not load properly. The map code works just fine on it's own.

How can I use the window on load function in conjunction with Google Maps to make both work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently google maps doesn't load if the target (`#map`) is hidden.

You can have a workaround by triggering the resize event of the maps once the target is visible, but do remember to move the center back to your desired location (lat/long).

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
map.setCenter({lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644}); // from OP's fiddle
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lfq1negw/1/